# how to debug an angular for loop

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do a batch upload of multiple pdfs. Each file is named in a specific format

> 02-2015 HIP BS32

date / pipeline abbreviation / location abbreviation.

I am running the files through a loop to compare the abbreviations to the list in the database. I then assign those properties to the object before it is passed to the API Controller. The pipeline and location tables are setup exactly the same. The issue I am having is with the pipeline. 
this is where the problem is,

```
$scope.pip = $scope.pipeLookup[matches[1]];
$scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matches[2]];
```

the locationLookup is matching the Location Abbreviation and placing it in the $scope.loc variable. However the pipeLookup is not working. It of course is throwing the error because the pipeline properties are undefined. I am not sure if I am just over looking something. if more information is needed then let me know
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

```
 $scope.companies = Company.query(function () { });
$scope.locations = Location.query(function () { });
$scope.pipes = Pipe.query(function () { });
$scope.selectCompany = function () {
    var id = $scope.companyId.CompanyId
    $http.get('/api/apiCompany/' + id)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.CompanyName = result.CompanyName
        });
};//

$scope.pipeLookup = {};
$scope.locationLookup = {};

$scope.upload = function () {
    var files = $scope.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];

            $scope.pipes.map(function (pip) {
                $scope.pipeLookup[pip['PipeAb']] = pip;
            });
            $scope.locations.map(function (loc) {
                $scope.locationLookup[loc['LocationAb']] = loc;
            });

            var matches = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);

            $scope.pip = $scope.pipeLookup[matches[1]];
            $scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matches[2]];

            $upload.upload({
                url: '/api/apiBatchPipeLine',
                fields: {
                    'typeId': 1,
                    'companyId': $scope.companyId.CompanyId,
                    'documentDate': $scope.model.documentDate,
                    'pipeId': $scope.pip['PipeId'],
                    'pipeName': $scope.pip['PipeName'],
                    'locationId': $scope.loc['LocationId'],
                    'locationAb': $scope.loc['LocationAb']
                },
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' +
                            JSON.stringify(data));
            }).error(function (err, result) {
                console.log(err, result);
            });

        }
    }
```

$scope.pipeLookup JSON

```
{"ANR ":{"$id":"1","PipeId":1,"PipeAb":"ANR ","PipeName":"Transcanada ANR Pipeline","Documents":null},"CGT ":{"$id":"2","PipeId":2,"PipeAb":"CGT ","PipeName":"Columbia Gulf Transmission","Documents":null},"CHA ":{"$id":"3","PipeId":3,"PipeAb":"CHA ","PipeName":"Enterprise Channel Pipeline","Documents":null},"FGT ":{"$id":"4","PipeId":4,"PipeAb":"FGT ","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Florida Gas Transmission","Documents":null},"GAB ":{"$id":"5","PipeId":5,"PipeAb":"GAB ","PipeName":"Enbridge Garden Banks Pipeline","Documents":null},"GLO ":{"$id":"6","PipeId":6,"PipeAb":"GLO ","PipeName":"American Midstream Gloria  Pipeline","Documents":null},"GSO ":{"$id":"7","PipeId":7,"PipeAb":"GSO ","PipeName":"Boardwalk Gulf South Pipeline","Documents":null},"HIO ":{"$id":"8","PipeId":8,"PipeAb":"HIO ","PipeName":"Enterprise High Island Offshore System","Documents":null},"HIP ":{"$id":"9","PipeId":9,"PipeAb":"HIP ","PipeName":"American Midstream High Point Pipeline","Documents":null},"HPL ":{"$id":"10","PipeId":10,"PipeAb":"HPL ","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Houston Pipeline","Documents":null},"TEJ ":{"$id":"11","PipeId":11,"PipeAb":"TEJ ","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tejas Pipeline","Documents":null},"KIN ":{"$id":"12","PipeId":12,"PipeAb":"KIN ","PipeName":"Kinetica Partners Pipeline","Documents":null},"NGP ":{"$id":"13","PipeId":13,"PipeAb":"NGP ","PipeName":" Kinder Morgan Natural Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},"SER ":{"$id":"14","PipeId":14,"PipeAb":"SER ","PipeName":" Energy Transfer Sea Robin Pipeline Company ","Documents":null},"SNT ":{"$id":"15","PipeId":15,"PipeAb":"SNT ","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Southern Natural Gas Company","Documents":null},"SRY ":{"$id":"16","PipeId":16,"PipeAb":"SRY ","PipeName":"MCPO Stingray Pipeline Company","Documents":null},"TGT ":{"$id":"17","PipeId":17,"PipeAb":"TGT ","PipeName":"Kinder Morgan Tennessee Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},"TET ":{"$id":"18","PipeId":18,"PipeAb":"TET ","PipeName":"Spectra Energy Texas Eastern Pipeline","Documents":null},"TXG ":{"$id":"19","PipeId":19,"PipeAb":"TXG ","PipeName":"Boardwalk Texas Gas Transmission","Documents":null},"TSC ":{"$id":"20","PipeId":20,"PipeAb":"TSC ","PipeName":"Williams Transcontinental Gas Pipeline","Documents":null},"TRK ":{"$id":"21","PipeId":21,"PipeAb":"TRK ","PipeName":"Energy Transfer Trunkline Gas Company","Documents":null},"VGS ":{"$id":"22","PipeId":22,"PipeAb":"VGS ","PipeName":"Targa Venice Gathering System","Documents":null}}
```

$scope.locationLookup Json

```
{"VR16":{"$id":"1","LocationId":1,"LocationAb":"VR16","LocationName":"Location VR16","Documents":null},"MP140\t":{"$id":"2","LocationId":2,"LocationAb":"MP140\t","LocationName":"Location MP140","Documents":null},"BS32":{"$id":"3","LocationId":3,"LocationAb":"BS32","LocationName":"Location BS32","Documents":null},"MP46":{"$id":"4","LocationId":4,"LocationAb":"MP46","LocationName":"Location MP46","Documents":null},"DF78":{"$id":"5","LocationId":5,"LocationAb":"DF78","LocationName":"Location DF78","Documents":null},"UR56":{"$id":"6","LocationId":6,"LocationAb":"UR56","LocationName":"Location UR56","Documents":null}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is expecting a dot (.) character at the end but your string doesn't contain a dot (.) at the end hence it is failing.

If I try your regex `^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\.` [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript) and pass in `02-2015 HIP BS32` it doesn't match because your regex is expecting a `.` literal at the end.

UPDATE: Here is a fragment of your pipeLookup JSON

```
"HIP ": {
"$id": "9",
"PipeId": 9,
"PipeAb": "HIP ",
"PipeName": "American Midstream High Point Pipeline",
"Documents": null
```

}

Here the key is "HIP " Notice the extra space after the `HIP`. This is why `$scope.pipeLookup[matches[1]]` returns nothing. Remove that trailing space before storing it in the `pipeLookup` object

Update: On more closer look, if the `file.name` contains this value `02-2015 HIP BS32` and if you want to get `HIP` value out of it you can use following regex

```
/^\d+\D\d+\s*(\S*\s*)(\S*)/i
```

Here is a [jsbin live demo](http://jsbin.com/yajopu/1/edit?js,console) of this regex example

Comment: var matches = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)/i);

Comment: What is the value inside matches[1] ? and also what are the values inside `$scope.pipeLookup` ? try wrapping the matches[1] in single or double quotes like `$scope.pipeLookup["'" + matches[1] + "'"]`

Comment: i posted the json of the $scope,pipeLookup.  I tried changing it but it didnt work.

Comment: how do i need to adjust the regex?